# Refresh ansible inventory at runtime with import_playbook

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x

I am trying to create a server and run a playbook on that host. To do this, I write the IP address to the host file and even try to add it to ansible memory. Then I import a playbook where the var target is the hosts value. But whatever I try, I cannot get it to work. Can someone shed some light?

The error I get is that I can't find the host

```
PLAY [localhost] ************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************

TASK [Gathering Facts] ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [get the roles directory] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [set the fact of role dir to output of last cmd] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [ls terrafrom workspace] ***********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Registering private IP as ansible variable.] **************************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Setting private IP as private_ip] *************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]

TASK [Now I will add 192.168.x.x to the ansible hosts file at /etc/ansible/hosts right under the line that [terrafrom] is on.] *******************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Now I will add the 192.168.x.x into ansibles memory] ***************************************************************************************************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [remove all files from ansible cache] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************
[WARNING]: Consider using the file module with state=absent rather than running 'rm'.  If you need to use command because file is insufficient you can add 'warn: false' to this command task or set
'command_warnings=False' in ansible.cfg to get rid of this message.
changed: [localhost]

TASK [Refresh ansible facts] ********************************************************************************************************************************************
ok: [localhost]
[WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: private_ip

PLAY [config {{ private_ip }}] **********************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
skipping: no hosts matched

PLAY RECAP ******************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************************
localhost                  : ok=10   changed=6    unreachable=0    failed=0    skipped=0    rescued=0    ignored=0
```

```yaml
---
# tasks file for mysql_linode_server
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - name: "Run terrafrom workspace"
      shell:
        cmd: "terraform apply -auto-approve"
        chdir: "{{ role_dir }}/terraform/mysql_one_node/"
    - name: "Registering private IP as ansible variable."
      shell:
        cmd: "terraform output -raw ip"
        chdir: "{{ role_dir }}/terraform/mysql_one_node/"
      register: private_ip
    - name: "Setting private IP as private_ip"
      set_fact:
        private_ip: "{{ private_ip.stdout }}"
    - name: "Now I will add {{ private_ip }} to the ansible hosts file at /etc/ansible/hosts right under the line that [terrafrom] is on."
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/ansible/hosts
        insertafter: "terraform"
        line: "{{ private_ip }}"
    - name: "Now I will add the {{ private_ip }} into ansibles inventory memory"
      ansible.builtin.add_host:
        name: "{{ private_ip }}"
        groups: terraform
    # I tried this to see if the inventory was cached.
    - name: remove all files from ansible cache
      shell:
        cmd: "rm -rfv ~/.ansible/tmp/* -rfv"
    # I refresh the inventory
    - name: Refresh inventory to ensure new instances exist in inventory
      ansible.builtin.meta: refresh_inventory
    # And even try to rebuild the facts.
    - name: Refresh ansible facts
      setup:

- name: "config {{ hostvars['localhost'].public_ip"
  import_playbook: "{{ playbook_dir }}/create_ansible_user.yml"
  vars:
    target: hostvars['localhost'].public_ip
```

I will be in the comments if you need any more info

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Given the file *hosts*

```yaml
shell> cat hosts
localhost
```

Let's create a simple playbook for testing

```yaml
shell> cat pb2.yml
- hosts: "{{ target }}"
  tasks:
    - debug:
        var: inventory_hostname
```

In the main playbook set the variable *private_ip* and add the host to the dynamic inventory. Then import the playbook *pb2.yml*

```yaml
shell> cat pb1.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        private_ip: 192.168.1.11
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ private_ip }}"
        groups: terraform
    
- import_playbook: pb2.yml
  vars:
    target: "{{ hostvars.localhost.private_ip }}"
```

This works as expected. Gives abridged

```yaml
shell> ansible-playbook pb1.yml
...
  inventory_hostname: 192.168.1.11
```

You'll get the same result when you add the line to the *hosts* and refresh the inventory

```yaml
shell> cat pb3.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        private_ip: 192.168.1.11
    - lineinfile:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/hosts"
        line: "{{ private_ip }}"
    - meta: refresh_inventory
    
- import_playbook: pb2.yml
  vars:
    target: "{{ hostvars.localhost.private_ip }}"
```

---

You'll also get the same result when you put the host both into the dynamic inventory and into the file *hosts*

```yaml
shell> cat pb4.yml
- hosts: localhost
  tasks:
    - set_fact:
        private_ip: 192.168.1.11
    - add_host:
        name: "{{ private_ip }}"
        groups: terraform
    - lineinfile:
        path: "{{ playbook_dir }}/hosts"
        line: "{{ private_ip }}"
    - meta: refresh_inventory
    
- import_playbook: pb2.yml
  vars:
    target: "{{ hostvars.localhost.private_ip }}"
```